# How are strained tomatoes different than tomato sauce?

Tags: tomatoes, italian-cuisine

I cook a lot of Italian dishes.  My wife likes tomato sauce, but can't stand chunky tomato flesh.  And so I have learned to make these dishes with strained tomatoes.

Recently I came across a recipe that called for diced tomatoes, and canned tomato sauce.  I replaced the diced tomatoes with strained tomatoes and noticed that it looks a lot like the tomato sauce.  They seem remarkably similar.

Are these two products the same?  If not, how do they differ?

Comment: ‘[Tomato sauce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tomato_sauce)’ can mean many different things in different places, from cooked chopped tomatoes to ketchup to various pasta sauces to tomato concentrate… Can you clarify which you mean?

Comment: You might even post the ingredients of a typical tomato sauce of the type you're thinking of - but then you'd have an answer.  (Where I am, the usual strained tomatoes have nothing added and if anything is added it's stated clearly on the front of the packet; that may not be the case where you are)

Comment: It's not a big deal that it got closed.  But the linked answer does not apply here.  Nowhere does it mention strained tomatoes.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger one answer at the linked question refers to "passata".  That's the same thing or as near as makes no difference

Comment: @JasonPSallinger "tomato purée" and "strained tomatoes" are pretty much synonymous. Using a strainer is a traditional method for making fruit and vegetable purées.

Comment: @rumtscho that's true by some definitions of "puree".   Here in the UK, our "puree" is some people's "paste"

Comment: @ChrisH this sounds like a good information to be added to the duplicate target in its own answer. Also, we have a huge community wiki translation question between different English dialects, it would probably be good for there too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the guidance, gidds and Chris H.

I looked up the ingredients for each:

**Tomato Sauce**

https://www.instacart.com/products/144591-redpack-tomato-sauce-8-oz

Ingredients: Tomato Puree (water, Tomato Paste From Vine-ripened Tomatoes), Water, Less Than 2% Of: Salt, Onion Powder, Garlic Powder, Citric Acid*, Natural Flavors, Dehydrated Bell Pepper.

**Strained Tomatoes**

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Pomi-Strained-Tomatoes/767465693

Ingredients: Tomatoes, Strained